# Can identityuser(CreateAsync, FindByNameAsync, etc.) methods be used in existing non-identityuser databases?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I have an simple existing database that look like this.

[database sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJBU3.png)

without using the `IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>` framework, can i access or utilize the methods like `CreateAsync`, `FindByNameAsync` and others?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this article (assuming you're using asp.netcore 3.1): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-custom-storage-providers?view=aspnetcore-3.1

You can use your own store, but there are several interfaces you need to implement to provide all the operations that the `UserManager<>` requires